# How to get dropdown/autocomplete suggestions to display on top of Modal in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete

I have a modal that prompts the users to enter some locations in an input field with autocomplete functionality. However, the autocomplete suggestions are displayed behind in the modal
[image]

Below is the code for my modal component. I am using MUI and `@reach/combobox`

```
const ContainerStyle = {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: { xs: 'column', md: 'row' },
    alignItems: 'center',
    bgcolor: 'background.paper',
    border: '1px solid #000',
    boxShadow: 24,
    borderRadius: '12px',
    margin: 0,
};


export const WelcomeModal = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(true)

    return ReactDOM.createPortal(<>
        <Modal
            aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
            aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
            open={open}
            onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
            closeAfterTransition
            BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
            BackdropProps={{
                timeout: 500,
            }}
        >
            <Box sx={ContainerStyle} >
                <StartPlaces />
                <EndPlaces />
            </Box>
        </Modal>
    </>, document.getElementById("portal"))
}
```

Below is the code for my `StartPlaces` component. `EndPlaces` component is identical.

```
export const StartPlaces = ()=>{
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const {ready, value, setValue, suggestions: {status, data}, clearSuggestions} = usePlacesAutocomplete();

    const handleSelect = async (val)=>{
        
        setValue(val, false);
        clearSuggestions();

        const results = await getGeocode({address: val});
        // console.log(results[0])
        const {lat, lng} = await getLatLng(results[0])
        dispatch(setOrigin({
            coordinates: {lat, lng},
            name: val
        }))
    }

    return<>
        <h4>Enter Origin</h4>
        <Combobox onSelect={handleSelect}>
            <ComboboxInput value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} className="combobox-input" placeholder="Houston, Texas" disabled={!ready}/>
            <ComboboxPopover>
                <ComboboxList style={{zIndex: 3000}}>
                    {status === "OK" && data.map(({place_id, description}) =><ComboboxOption key={place_id} value={description}/>)}
                </ComboboxList>
            </ComboboxPopover>
        </Combobox>
    </>
}
```

I couldnt think of a reason why this is happening since I am rendering everything in the `portal`. I tried messing with the `zIndex` in my `ComboboxList` but it doesnt seem to work. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated :) Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ive been able to work around my problem by using MUI's autocomplete, but i would still like to know what I did wrong in my previous attempt, or what else was needed for my code.  If anyone is curious to how my MUI component looks like             
`
  <Autocomplete 
        id="free-solo-demo"
        freeSolo
        options={data.map(({description}) => description)}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Origin" onChange={(e)=>handleSelect(e.target.value)} placeholder="e.g. Las Vegas"/>}
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
      />
`